# MySqlCommand - Parameter insertion not working properly

Tags: c#

I am inserting data from data grid to MySQL table and the insertion works fine and data gets inserted but at the end it gives the error, saying that "sid" cannot be null although the data is inserted to the table. please check my code.

```
        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(@"connectionstring");         
        string query = "insert into excel_table (sid,name,fathername)values(@sid,@name,@fathername)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
        cn.Open();       

        foreach(DataRowView dr in gridxl.ItemsSource)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", dr["sid"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", dr["name"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathername", dr["fathername"]);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        cn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("saved!");
```

Comment: (Probably) not related, but be aware of the [pitfalls of `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: So, is `sid` null at the end of the execution process?

Comment: What is the `excel_table  `table definition?

Comment: you have not allowed null for "sid" but somehow dr["sid"] is returning null

Comment: @JevgeniGeurtsen it inserts the id to the table

Comment: @codefan , it's probably due to the fact that in datagridview last row is always empty, i'm pretty sure that if you comment  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", dr["sid"]); the new error message will be "name cannot be null" try it and tell us .

Comment: @RahulTripathi excel_table is table name

Comment: @VERYNET i think that's the case so how can i prevent that??

Comment: @codefan look at my answer

Comment: Maybe there is empty row at the end of the ItemSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# , datagridview last row is **always empty** .

If you display your datas there will be everytime an empty row , you can check it easily , and that's why you got this error .

To remove this empty row you can use :

**EDIT code for WPF** :

Just add

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly ="true"/>
```

or

```
<DataGridTextColumn CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly ="true"/>
```

in XAML

Comment: it's a datagrid in wpf not a gridview and datagrid items source is excel file

Comment: @codefan did you still see the empty row at the end of your datagrid with this parameter or there is no change ? Cause if you can still see an empty row, that mean that you didn't implements this property rightly.

Comment: before data is loaded to the grid there is an empty field, but when data is loaded that fielded is gone . there is no change when i use ur code

Comment: @codefan Well if you're sure that when data is loaded, the last row IS NOT EMPTY , that mean that you got an empty information somewhere . Can you please test your function just by inserting the parameter "fathername" to see if the error persist .

Comment: i still have the issue

Comment: @codefan but what is now the error if you only add "fatherename" ?

Comment: @i can't delete id because it's primary key and cn't be null

Comment: @codefan ok, all your informations are inserted in base before the program crashed you sure ?

Comment: @ VERYNET yes, that's true, when i check the table i see the data and i tested many times

Comment: @codefan try to put this in your datagrid XAML : IsReadOnly="True"

Comment: I added the code to datagrid xaml but still error comes :-(

Comment: @codefan i edited the code in my answer did you got the same ?

Comment: yea mate..still cmd.executeNonQuery error" id" cannot be null.

Comment: @codefan , i got an idea maybe instead of doing your insert in your foreach, try to display the id in console or whatever to see when it get null !

Comment: @ VERYNET thanks alot for your time , i'll update if any changes occur

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is empty row at the end of the ItemSource?

Try:

```
    foreach(DataRowView dr in gridxl.ItemsSource)
    {
        if (dr["sid"] != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", dr["sid"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", dr["name"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathername", dr["fathername"]);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please put this as commnent